# Array of real to binary (0/1)

Tags: fortran

I have an array :

```
 0.3  0.4  0.65  1.45
-1.2  6.0 -3.49  3.9
```

And I would like to have 0 if value is negative and 1 if positive :

```
1  1  1  1
0  1  0  1
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop like:

```
DO X=1,Xmax
 Do Y=1,Ymax
  IF(Array(X,Y)>0)THEN
     Array(X,Y)=1
  END IF
 END DO
END DO
```

Comment: There are multiple ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having way too much fun with this.  This one does not require that the numbers fit into integers:

```
ARRAY = 0.5 * ARRAY / ABS(ARRAY) + 0.5
```

Comment: That is the `sign`, just slower.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of the `where` approach as given by [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266028/), but I can also suggest a related one.

`merge` is an intrinsic elemental function which takes two sources and a mask:

```
array = MERGE(0., 1., array.lt.0.)
```

As a slight correction to Vladimir F's `sign`:

```
array = SIGN(0.5, array) + 0.5
```

Note the switching of order compared with the other answer.

With the elemental nature of `merge` and `sign` it is possible to mix scalar desired values with the array and array mask.

As both of these can naturally be modified to assign the value to another variable (even creating an integer one), I'll show an alternative `where` for completeness:

```
where (array.lt.0.)
  another_array=0
elsewhere
  another_array=1
end where
```

for `another_array` appropriately shaped.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward

```
where (array>=0)
  array = 1
else where
  array = 0
end where
```

<strike>it is not very handy that the sign function needs another array for the magnitudes, because</strike>

```
array = sign(array, halfs) + 0.5
```

requires an array with 0.5's of the same shape as `array`.

Actually it should be `array = sign(0.5, array) + 0.5` as shown by francescalus. I even looked into the manual and then switched the arguments anyway...

Comment: I'm old-fashioned.  I use `.GE.`

Comment: Maybe should avoid answering on my phone.

Comment: My gfortran compiler doesn't like that: "Error: ‘b’ argument of ‘sign’ intrinsic at (1) must be the same type and kind as ‘a’"

Comment: Did you do the same error as me in my test an hour ago? :) (`real(10)::a` instead of `real:: a(10)`)

Comment: No.  I'm using a 4x4 array: `REAL*8 :: ARRAY(4,4)`

Comment: Then it should work. Just remember to use correct kind for the `0.5`. BTW, `real*8` is not legal standard Fortran and has no direct analogue in literals.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but if you want a one-liner:

```
ARRAY = CEILING( ARRAY / CEILING(ABS(ARRAY)) )
```

Comment: Hmmm...  Found test cases where it doesn't work.  Y'all might want to "unlike" it.

Comment: Can add a little fudge factor to make it work: `ARRAY = CEILING( ARRAY / CEILING(ABS(ARRAY-1.0E-9)) )`.

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir wants FAST!

```
  REAL(KIND=8) :: ARRAY(4,2) = RESHAPE ( &
       (/ 0.3, 0.4, 0.65, 1.45, -1.2, 6.0, -3.49, 3.9 /), (/4,2/) )
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: IARRAY(4,2)
  EQUIVALENCE (ARRAY, IARRAY)

  ARRAY = 1 - IBITS( IARRAY,63,1 )
```

:D

Comment: kind=8 is soo ugly. You can better stay at real*8... But here where working with bits, that is really the exact place for int64 and real64. But wheter that is better than the OP's code? I want saying I need something fast, it is not my question after all. Just that computing `sign` by floating point multiplication, when there is `sign` available as intrinsic, is just pointles, more complicated (and slower).

Comment: But the main point is that I like the `sign` version, as corrected by francescalus, the most.

Comment: It's not working for me. Using gfortran, `array = SIGN(0.5, array) + 0.5` gives the following error: `Error: ‘b’ argument of ‘sign’ intrinsic at (1) must be the same type and kind as ‘a’`

Comment: Because you must use the right kind for the `0.5` (as I said already). You use some form of double precision `array` in your tests, so `0.5` must be also double precision. We just used single precision to keep stuff simple.